# iText7 split text in two columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, itext7

I wanna build a pdf and display text in two columns if the text in the first column reaches the bottom of the current page. If the text needs multiple pages, the first column text in the next page should continue where the second column text in the previous page ended.

I have tried with tables but it doesn't work because i don't know if a cell will reach the bottom of the page

Comment: Have you tried using the iText 7 `ColumnDocumentRenderer`?

Comment: Thank you @mkl, i didn't see that

Comment: In that case you might also be interested in this iText knowledgebase article: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-net/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers-net